# Ancestry with App.addRegions

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

If you add a region to a layout view using the regions hash like so:

```
regions: {
        compositeRegion: '@ui.compositeViewDiv',
        modalRegion:{
            regionClass:modal,
            selector:'.modalRegion'
        }
    }
```

The views that you show in those regions can call triggerMethod and trigger an event on their parent view.

If instead I build my regions (for instance, in a composite view or even an item view) like so:

```
App.addRegions({
        compositeRegion: '@ui.compositeViewDiv',
        modalRegion:{
            regionClass:modal,
            selector:'.modalRegion'
    }
```

Nothing happens when you call triggerMethod. It does not seem to have the _parent attribute defined on the region.

If I manually set _parent to any view, it will trigger a method on the next highest up layout view.

For example, I have a Layout view "A" with a composite view "B", and that composite view "B" has an item view "C". If I create a region using App.addRegions code above in the item view "C", I can then set the _parent and show a view like so:

```
App.modalRegion._parent = this;    
App.modalRegion.show(new someView());
```

The Layout view "A" childEvent is triggered, not the item view "C", nor the Composite view "B".

If I manually call

```
this.triggerMethod('sameeventname');
```

on the item view "C", it WILL trigger the composite view "B"'s childEvent.

Any ideas? I need to be able to use my modal region (takes any marionette view and turns it into a jQuery-UI modal) from anywhere. It works great when you use it with the layout view region hash. But since there is no region hash in a composite or item view, it works but will not communicate with its parent view.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at James Kyle's [Marionette Wires](https://github.com/thejameskyle/marionette-wires), in particular the way services are used to display global components such as modal and flashes in his example.

The basic architecture is an application, with a `LayoutView` containing a region for each component. This is rendered on initialize and the component is passed the region from the app.

For rendering a view in a modal something like the following should work:

```
//layout-view.js
import { LayoutView } from 'backbone.marionette';

export const BaseLayout = LayoutView.extend({
  regions: {
    modal: '.modal',
    ...
  }
});

//app.js
import { Application } from 'backbone.marionette';
import { BaseLayout } from './layout-view';

export const App = Application.extend({
  initialize(options = {}) {
    this.layout = new Layout({
      el: options.el
    });
    this.layout.render();
  }
});

//modal/service.js
import { Service } from 'backbone.service';

const ModalService = Service.extend({
  setup(options = {}) {
    this.container = options.container;
  },

  requests: {
    show: 'show',
    hide: 'hide'
  },

  show(view) {
    this.container.show(view);
  },

  hide() {
    this.container.empty()
  }
});

export const modalService = new ModalService();

//main.js
import { App } from './app';
import { modalService } from './modal/service';

const app = new App({
  el: '.root-element'
});

modalService.setup({
  container: app.layout.modal
});

.... init other components


//someComponent/index.js

import { modalService } from '../modal/service';

...

  showView() {
    const view = new View();
    modalService.request('show', view)
      .then(doSomething)
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  },

  hideView() {
    modalService.request('hide')
      .then(doSomething);
  }
```

Comment: These modals aren't meant to be global though - they are created by and need to respond to the same view.